# Proof that a quocient set is homeomorphic to \mathbb{R}

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations

I'm having trouble solving this:

> Consider $X:=\mathbb{R}$ with equivalence relation:
> $$xRy \iff x=y  \text{ or }  x,y\in [0,1].$$
> Proof that $X/R$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$.

How do I write the set $X/R$?

I can't find the funcition for the homeomorphism.

Comment: Conceptually you're replacing the interval $[0,1]$ with a single point. Find a function from $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is a homeomorphism then splice it on the interval to give you a constant, say $0$, from the interval. A piecewise linear function would be simple.

Comment: The relation you have written either doesn't make sense or is not an equivalence relation. Under what condition on $x,y$ should it hold that $xRy$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann It makes perfect sense, the points in $[0,1]$ are in the same partition, every other partition is a singleton.

Comment: @CyclotomicField That would be written as
$$
xRy \iff x=y \text{ or } x,y \in [0,1].
$$
I don't understand how it is possible to read the description given and come to the conclusion you came to

Comment: @BenGrossmann $x=y$ is the equivalence relation being defined, not the usual equal sign.

Comment: @CyclotomicField Having written that out, it occurs to me that $\forall$ could be a replacement for $\lor$.

Comment: @CyclotomicField I have no idea what you mean by that. For me, the line $xRy \iff x=y \ \forall \ x,y\in [0,1]$ reads as "$xRy$ holds ($x$ "is related to" $y$) if and only if $x = y$ for all $x,y \in [0,1]$"

Comment: Yes, exactly, the definition of $R$ should read as $(x=y){\pmb\lor}(x,y\in [0,1])$.

Comment: Ok, I  fixed it, it realy was "or" and not forall. But I still don't understand  how to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
x & x < 0 \\
0 & 0 \le x \le 1\\
x-1 & x > 1
\end{cases}
$$
Then $f$ is continuous, and for every $u \in \Bbb R$, $f^{-1}(\{u\})$ is the equivalence class containing $u$. That should make it easy to find a homeomorphism.